# Parse-Server: How can I create a log file on the outside?

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I use Parse-Server on Heroku.

I can see server log via parse dashboard. However, it disappears at deployment time.

Is it possible to write logs to external storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can access to your logs like that: `heroku logs -n 1500`

If you want more than 1500 log lines, you should use an [addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#logging) or [Log Drains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains)

So you can redirect your log to a file or an external storage, for example you can write:

```
heroku logs -n 1500 --app application_name >> file_logs.txt
```

There also use [FileLoggerAdapter](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/wiki/FileLoggerAdapter.js) from parse you can use it like that:

```
fileLogger.info('info content', {} => {...});
fileLogger.info('error content', {} => {...});
fileLogger.query({
  level: 'error',
  size: 10,
  from: Date.now() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
  until: Date.now(),
  order: 'desc'
}, {} => {...})
```